# How to calculate the expected value of the product of two random variables in a hierarchical model?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value, hierarchical-bayesian

Consider the model:
\begin{align} 
 & X \sim p_1()\\
 & Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y)\\
 & \mu_Y \sim p_2()\\
 & \sigma_Y \sim p_3()\\
\end{align}
where $p_1()$, $p_2()$, and $p_3()$ are prior probability distributions.

How to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y)$, without assuming independence between X and Y, using samples from joint probability density function $p(X,\mu_Y,\sigma_Y)$  (e.g., the trace of MCMC calcualtions) ?

Comment: How is the lack of independence of $(X,Y)$ achieved?  Nothing in your present formulation implies there is dependence.

Comment: This is a very thought-provoking comment! I understand that the way the problem is set up with the prior distributions does not imply dependence between the RVs. However, I am concerned that the dataset I am using to calibrate the model might induce a dependence between the RVs X, Y.